# Objective-C method implementation nuances

Tags: objective-c, xcode, methods, implementation, compiler-warnings

I have just started to develop for the iPhone and am in the process of learning Objective-C.  I have seen some code that implements a method in the @implementation side of a class like this:

```
-(void)myMethod; {
  // method body
}
```

What makes this interesting is that there is no mention of myMethod in the @interface for the class.  I tried a sample project with this and when I compile I get a warning from XCode that myMethod may not be seen by the calling code.

Can anyone tell me what is going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's just like functions in C. You don't need a declaration (i.e. it doesn't have to be in the `@interface`) but if there's no declaration, any code *before* the method definition will generate that warning. Code *after* the method definition will not generate a warning.

Answer (score 0):

In ObjC, method calls are resolved dynamically ([dynamic binding](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Articles/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW10)), meaning that when you do `[obj myMethod];`, internally the ObjC runtime software will go through the class methods *at that point in time* and if it finds one called "myMethod" it will then call it.

Also it is possible to add methods to an object at runtime.

The method declarations in an `@interface` section is only there to help the compiler determine what methods are publicly available for a given class. If you do add a method in your `@implementation` only, the compiler may warn you about that, but the code will still compile and work.

I sometimes use this to add internal methods to my objects, which are only called from other methods after it, and never from outside. Though I don't remember seeing warnings about it... Make sure that the calling code is placed **after** the method implementation in the same file.

Comment: It may be the semicolon after the method name causing the warning.  When writing unit test classes I always omit the declaration in the @interface and I never see such warnings.

Comment: @JeremyP Nope, semicolon is legal. In fact, it is pretty neat that you don't have to edit method headers when copy-pasting them from `@interface` and back.